# How to deal with specific client configuration and apk

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, configuration-files

im mostly a web developer but for one project i have to to create a mobile app certainly with xamarin.

As we deliver our webapp to each client we will also distribute the mobile app to each client.

The problem is that each client have specific configuration, for example, the url of the webservice the mobile app will connect.

My idea was to build the apk on my side, deploy it on each client and let a configuration file specific on each client (actually this configuration file exist because it is used by the webapp).

But it seem impossible in the mobile world, it seem the apk need embed everything.

Im surprised i don't find so much documentation about this, it seem nobody else seem concerned by this problem.

How do you guy deal with that ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I can think of multiple ways of getting the Client App configured.

1. Make a unique App for each customer, which is preconfigured. This can be done using CI and some configuration files.
2. Have the Client App configure itself, this could be either by

   - Scanning a QR code that directs the App to its configuration
   - Entering a Pin code that directs the App to its configuration
   - Having the customer host a Web API locally, with a specific DNS name, which your App gets configured by
3. Have the customer selecting a configuration from a list
4. Have the customer entering a URL for the configuration
5. If the customer has to sign in to the App, use that to identify their organization and select the configuration based on that

Just some different ideas how to solve your problem. Some are more involved than others.